# SyncFusion SfRichTextBoxAdv weird suspensive points while typping

Tags: wpf, syncfusion

When typping text in a SfRichTextBox, the current word that I am writting appears incomplette with three points at the end. Once the space bar is pressed, the word appears properly. Is is similar to the TextTrimming property set as "CharacterEllipsis" on a TextBlock control. I would like to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Greetings from Syncfusion,

We were able to reproduce the reported issue while using our control inside the [TabControlExt](https://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/tabcontrol/overview) when the strip placement is other than top. Please refer the below screenshot.
[Clipping issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3Qzi.png)

If you are facing the above same issue and you are using SfRichTextBoxAdv control inside the TabControlExt with strip placement is other than top, like below code snippet. Make sure you are using latest release version of our product (17.4.0.39). Because, we have fixed similar issues and included in our volume 4 main release which is delivered on last month.

```
<Grid>
    <syncfusion:TabControlExt TabStripPlacement="Left" >
        <syncfusion:TabItemExt Header="Support" Height="30">
            <syncfusion:SfRichTextBoxAdv  LayoutType="Continuous" />
        </syncfusion:TabItemExt>
    </syncfusion:TabControlExt>
</Grid>
```

If still you are facing the same issue, please share your code snippet or sample with replication steps to reproduce the issue. Because it will help us to provide you the appropriate solution at the earliest.

For further details, please create a new incident (under your account) from our support website to provide solution quickly. Please find the support website link from below. 
https://www.syncfusion.com/support/directtrac/incidents/newincident

Note: I work for Syncfusion

Answer (score 0):

We have placed the control inside a Grid. a piece of code below...

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0"
          Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,5"
                   Text="Vista previa del documento de texto." />

        <Syncfusion:SfRichTextBoxAdv Grid.Row="1"
                                     Grid.Column="1"
                                     Background="LightGray"
                                     DocumentTitle="Hola"
                                     LayoutType="Pages" />
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

We have tried to reproduce the reported issue with the provided code snippet, but we couldn’t face any clipping issue while typing the text. And we suspect that this issue occurs only on specific application. So, please share your sample application to reproduce the reported issue.

For quick response, please create a new incident (under your account) from our support website to provide solution quickly. Please find the support website link from below. 
https://www.syncfusion.com/support/directtrac/incidents/newincident

Note: I work for Syncfusion